# Modeling crossword-construction in z3

Tags: z3, smt, sat

I'm working on a program to generate crossword puzzles. The task is: given a grid, is there a way to fill the grid with letters such that each clue (acrosses and downs) is a valid word?

This can be pretty naturally reduced to boolean satisfiablity - have booleans for "does $LETTER appear at $ROW, $COL?" and "is $WORD the answer to $CLUE?", and then add constraints between the two sets of booleans. I've had some success modeling it this way with SAT solvers.

I've been wondering if I can get better results with the richer API that z3 provides, but I feel like I'm holding it wrong. I've started by attempting to replicate the SAT approach (a bunch of Bools and assertions), but just *creating* the O(10k) constraint clauses takes around 15 minutes, never mind actually solving it. I've tried using both the Python and Rust bindings with the same results. For comparison's sake, `varisat` (a less mature SAT-solver written in Rust) does the loading *and* the solving in well under a second.

Is there a better way to programmatically specify this many constraints? Is there a better way of modeling this problem for z3? Is this just not the kind of thing z3 is good at?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see https://bohlender.pro/blog/generating-crosswords-with-sat-smt/?

It’s hard to opine without seeing your exact program. But looks like the above blog has a good handle on this problem. Reading through it and asking specific questions would be more suitable in the stack overflow context.